# GitLab runner sharing hardware with manual operations

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'd like to perform automated tests that require the use of special hardware. The engineers also use this hardware for manual tests.

Is there a way to make runner selection conditional on a call to an external API?

The sequence I'd like to see is

- GitLab reserves a runner so no other jobs can be scheduled before it
- GitLab invokes the external API to reserve the hardware for this job
- On success, GitLab schedules the job to the runner
- On failure, GitLab selects a different runner or waits for a few minutes